# Access QML root object from C++ QML type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a custom QML type written in C++, the classname is **MyCustomType** and it's located in the files *mycustomtype.h* and *mycustomtype.cpp*.

In the *main.cpp* file the QML type is made available:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyCustomType>("MyCustomType", 1, 0, "MyCustomType");

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("../qml/main.qml")));
```

In the *main.cpp* file I can get access to the engine's root object like this:

```
rootObject = static_cast<QQuickWindow *> (engine.rootObjects().first());
```

My issue is that I need access to that rootObject from within the MyCustomType class in the *mycustomtype.cpp* file. Is that possible?

The only way I could think of was to pass the rootObject to the constructor. But since the MyCustomType is instatiated in the QML document, and not in C++ code, this solution won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to access to the root object? This will help to answer your question. Do you need access to the parent of your object? A set of properties you added in the root object ? Access to the application window? Ability to call signal or functions of the root? etc.

Comment: The MyCustomType is setting up a video stream using GStreamer and I need to start the pipeline using the method _scheduleRenderJob_ from the rootObject (QQuickWindow).

Comment: If your type is a `QQuickItem` you can use `QQuickItem::window()` to access the window where the item is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on GrecKo's comment.

Instead of making MyCustomType extend QObject, I made it extend QQuickItem. Then it's possible to call window() from anywhere in that class and get the root object. This is simple and it works.

**mycustomtype.h:**

```
class MyCustomType : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyCustomType(QQuickItem *parent = 0);

}
```

**mycustomtype.cpp**

```
MyCustomType::MyCustomType(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickItem(parent)
{
    QQuickWindow *rootObject = window();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Passing the root object**

You can use [`setContextProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) to make a variable globally available in QML:

```
engine.rootContext ().setContextProperty("rootObject", QVariant::fromValue(engine.rootObjects().first()));
```

Now you can access the root object in QML using `rootObject` and pass it to `MyCustomType` during construction.

**Method 2: Make the root object statically available**

You can make the root object statically available. One clean solution is to create a singleton class with all your global data members.

Comment: @KMK: If you instantiate it in QML, than that is exactly the way to do it. It is not recommended to use C++-code to access the object tree, to fetch or inject objects from there, as this would require a deep knowledge of the object tree.

Comment: @m7913d: I tried to implement it, but ran into a problem because the context property of the rootObject was set after the QML view had been interpreted. I couldn't find a clean way to receive a signal when rootObject changed, so I went with a solution based on GrecKo's comment. Thanks anyway :)